# Drupal Search Programmatically

Tags: 6, search

I need to implement my own search method in order to find nodes with some keywords in their title or body and with a specific type, but I don't know how to do this.

I tried with `do_search()` and `node_search()` methods but I don't get results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`node_search()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_search/6) is the implementation of [`hook_search()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_search/6) from the node module and is used by the search module to provide the search interface available at `/search`. [`do_search()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/do_search/6) looks more like in internal function to build query against the full-text index maintained by the search module.

`node_search()` can be used from custom code to query the node full-text index. But it doesn't support content type filtering nor does it support search on specific fields. Technically, it seems that a custom call to `do_search()` with the right arguments could do the trick, but looking at how `node_search()` uses it, this doesn't seems easy.

It is probably easier to build a custom search page with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) as it support field-based full-text search.

Comment: yeah but i'm developing the whole module so i'm trying to avoid Views. There's no other ways to search nodes in drupal?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using Views in custom code since they can be exported to code. Either manually or using the Features module.

Answer (score 3):

The function to use in this case is [`search_data()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_data/6), which formats the search result obtained using the value passed in `$key` (the first parameter). The function is used by [`search_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/search_view/6.x), the menu callback used by Drupal to show the search result and the search form.

```php
function search_view($type = 'node') {
 if (!isset($_POST['form_id'])) {
    if ($type == '') {
      drupal_goto('search/node');
    }
    $keys = search_get_keys();

    $results = '';
    if (trim($keys)) {
      watchdog('search', '%keys (@type).', array(
        '%keys' => $keys,
        '@type' => module_invoke($type, 'search', 'name'),
      ), WATCHDOG_NOTICE, l(t('results'), 'search/' . $type . '/' . $keys));

      $results = search_data($keys, $type);
      if ($results) {
        $results = theme('box', t('Search results'), $results);
      }
      else {
        $results = theme('box', t('Your search yielded no results'), search_help('search#noresults', drupal_help_arg()));
      }
    }

    $output = drupal_get_form('search_form', NULL, $keys, $type);
    $output .= $results;
    return $output;
  }
  return drupal_get_form('search_form', NULL, empty($keys) ? '' : $keys, $type);
}
```

If you are writing custom code to search nodes, that code should be used as start.

Answer (score 1):

See if the [Search API Module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) provides you with what you need.

Comment: i'm using drupal 6 so i can't install it. Thanks anyway